# How to use where clause for 2 arrays and get response by each array item?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, where-clause

I am trying to get response with "Where, where_in clause" like below but it is only checking 1 arrays value to another. I want to create filter here

```
Table name = asp_product_list
server_cat_id = 1 (Server table/Column) (VARCHAR / TEXT)
filter_cat_id = [1, 3, 2] (Filter selected values)
```

MY CODE:

```
if (isset($_POST['filter_cat_id']) && $_POST['filter_cat_id'] != "") {
     $catsFLT = explode(", ", $_POST['filter_cat_id']);
     $this->db->where_in('server_cat_id', $catsFLT);
}
```

Above code works perfect with single value available in server_cat_id like above shown situation.

But I don't know how to check 2 arrays with where clause and get response like below case

```
Table name = asp_product_list
server_cat_id = 1,2,3,6 (Server table/Column) (VARCHAR / TEXT)
& filter_cat_id = [1, 3, 2] (Filter selected values)
```

Then it gives me blank array.

Any help?

Comment: FYI `isset($_POST['filter_cat_id']) && $_POST['filter_cat_id'] != ""` === `!empty($_POST['filter_cat_id'])` . Also, why do you have comma-separated strings being posted? Why isn't it coming as an array?  Are you asking how to write `where_in()` twice?  I find your question to be Unclear.

Comment: sorry as I am new to php I dont know how to explain some things that much easily... But what I want is, I want to check if any(single id) id from "filter_cat_id" is available in "server_cat_id"(array list). If yes(id is there in server_cat_id array) then give response with data I want else it would return null.

Comment: First your question is not clear at all. Please edit your question and we can help you. Post your controller and model code. Better use $this->input->post() instead of $_POST. This code you post look like your model but in model you cannot use $_POST how you do this?